# Action Mailer: How do I render dynamic data in an email body that is stored in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have Action Mailer setup to render an email using the body attribute of my Email model (in the database).  I want to be able to use erb in the body but I can't figure out how to get it to render in the sent email message.

I'm able to get the body as a string with this code

```
# models/user_mailer.rb
def custom_email(user, email_id)
  email = Email.find(email_id)

  recipients    user.email
  from          "Mail It Example <admin@foo.com>"
  subject       "Hello From Mail It"
  sent_on       Time.now

  # pulls the email body and passes a string to the template views/user_mailer/customer_email.text.html.erb
  body          :msg => email.body
end
```

I came across this article http://rails-nutshell.labs.oreilly.com/ch05.html which says I can use `render` but I'm only able to get `render :text` to work and not `render :inline`

```
# models/user_mailer.rb
def custom_email(user, email_id)
  email = Email.find(email_id)

  recipients    user.email
  from          "Mail It Example <admin@foo.com>"
  subject       "Hello From Mail It"
  sent_on       Time.now

  # body          :msg => email.body
  body          :msg => (render :text => "Thanks for your order")  # renders text and passes as a variable to the template
  # body          :msg => (render :inline => "We shipped <%= Time.now %>")  # throws a NoMethodError

end
```

**Update:** Someone recommended using `initialize_template_class` on this thread **http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/67820**.  I now have this for `body`

```
body          :msg => initialize_template_class(:user => user).render(:inline => email.body)
```

It works but I don't understand this so I tried researching the private method and there is not much out there on it which makes me worry this is a hack and there is probably a better way.  **Suggestions?**

Comment: What's the NoMethod error? These are the most informative errors ruby will ever give you.

Comment: The error is "NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you end up unable to use render :inline, you can always instantiate ERb yourself.

```
  require 'erb'

  x = 42
  template = ERB.new <<-EOF
    The value of x is: <%= x %>
  EOF
  puts template.result(binding)

  #binding here is Kernel::binding, the current variable binding, of which x is a part.
```

Answer (score 6):

In rails 3.2 :inline method of render works just fine.

```
  mail(:to => "someemail@address.com",
       :subject => "test") do |format|
    format.text { render :inline => text_erb_content }
    format.html { render :inline => html_erb_content }
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Tim's suggestion is on the right path.  Here is how you implement ERB in the email action

```
def custom_email(user, email_id)
  email = Email.find(email_id)
  # more email setup ...
  body            :msg => ERB.new(email.body).result(binding)
  # or ...
  # body            :msg => ERB.new(email.body).result(user.send(:binding))
end
```

The difference between the two hashes will determine what erb you user in the body attribute in the database table.  With the first you have to use `<%= user.name %>` to access your use.  With the second you can just do `<%= name %>`